# Add incrementing field on update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

What would be the correct syntax to do the following in mysql?

```
SET @inc = 1;
update platform set package_id=(@inc := 1) where platform != 'hello';
```

Basically, I just want to create a pseudo-auto-incrementing field here, but it seems this just sets everything to `1`. What would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Set it like this:

```
SET @inc = 0;
update platform set package_id=(@inc := @inc + 1) where platform != 'hello';
```